# Django use of url

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to use the following type approach in an .html file:

```
<a href="{% url xxx.views.login %}">Login</a>
```

where I have in urls.py the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    (r'^login/$', 'xxx.views.login'),
```

But I get the following error:

```
Could not import xxx.views.accounts. View does not exist in module xxx.views.
```

Not sure if this is something pretty obvious. Is this the correct format for urls?

If I try in urls.py:

```
(r'^login/$', 'xxx.views.login', name='login'),
```

with in the .html file:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 13)
```

If I change the .html file to:

```
<a href="{% url login %}">Login</a>
```

I get:

```
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Comment: <a href="{% url 'xxx.views.login' %}">Login</a>

Comment: Hmm. I thought strings were implicit, I tried but still get ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import xxx.views.accounts. View does not exist in module jelt.views.

Comment: the template and the url that you put the name of the url was
"xxx.views.login",
but the error is as
"accounts".see there just right, it is weird

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'xxx.views.login' %}"> Login </a>
```

but the best would be to name the url:

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'xxx.views.login', name="login"),
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url login %}">Login</a>
```

Since 1.5:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: if I try adding the name component to urls.py I get the folowing: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 13)

Comment: if you are naming a url
 you have to use the url function
 using only one tuple will actually give a syntax error

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to work either. Is thi something in the settings.py file?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not with the login URL. It only happens there because the url reverse functionality triggers the import of all your URLs. There is a problem with the URL that references `accounts`. Does that view actually exist?

Comment: Yes, I have now commented this out.

Comment: I think that might have been one issue as I was developing, but can't seem to get the right format now for including the urls in the template.